# Sql server version problem when database restore

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

When I want to backup the SQL Server database, I get this error:

> the database backup on a server running version 10.50.1600 that
>   version incompatible with this server
>   which is running version 10.00.4000

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like maybe you are trying to restore a SQL 2008 R2 backup on a SQL 2008 server; Unfortunately, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: That is **definitely not** possible - never has, probably never will. You **cannot** restore a backup from one SQL Server version on an system running an earlier version of SQL Server - no tricks, no tools - just no way.

Answer (score 2):

Backup & Restore is not possible but you can try generating database script with data and run the script on the destination server.
To do this:
Right-Click on the database...
Tasks >> Generate Scripts
... on the Options page of the wizard set "Script Data" to true.

You can also set the script compatibility by selecting "Script for Server Version" field.