# SQL Server version problem when database restore

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sql server version problem when database restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566397/sql-server-version-problem-when-database-restore)

I would like to restore a database, but I get follow error message:

> the database backup on a server
>   running version 10.50.1600 that
>   version incompatible with this server
>   which is running version 10.00.4000

What should I do to update my SQL Server 2008 to this version?

I have already installed service packs 1 & 2 for SQL Server. But the restore of the database still doesn’t work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Your backup is from SQL Server 2008 **R2** (version 10.5)
- You are trying to restore onto SQL Server 2008 (version 10.0)

It can't be done

You'll need to:

- upgrade target server to SQL Server 2008 R2
- use SSIS to migrate the schema and data
- use SSMS wizards to migrate the schema and data